# Rescaling the plot of a tree with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following code in gnuplot to draw a tree from different inputs.

```
### tree diagram with gnuplot
reset session

#ID  Parent   Name   Colors   shape


# put datablock into strings
IDs = Parents = Names = Colors = Shape = ""
set table $Dummy
    plot "tmp.dat" u (IDs = IDs.strcol(1)." "): \
             (Parents = Parents.strcol(2)." "): \
             (Names = Names.strcol(3)." "): \
             (Colors = Colors.strcol(4)." "): \
             (Shape = Shape.strcol(5)." ") w table
unset table

# Top node has no parent ID "NaN"
Start(n) = int(sum [i=1:words(Parents)] (word(Parents,i) eq "NaN" ? int(word(IDs,i)) : 0))

# get list index by ID
ItemIdx(s,n) = n == n ? (tmp=NaN, sum [i=1:words(s)] ((word(s,i)) == n ? (tmp=i,0) : 0), tmp) : NaN

# get parent of ID n
Parent(n) = word(Parents,ItemIdx(IDs,n))

# get level of ID n, recursive function
Level(n) = n == n ? Parent(n)>0 ? Level(Parent(n))-1 : 0 : NaN

# get number of children of ID n
ChildCount(n) = int(sum [i=1:words(Parents)] (word(Parents,i)==n))

# Create child list of ID n
ChildList(n) = (Ch = " ", sum [i=1:words(IDs)] (word(Parents,i)==n ? (Ch = Ch.word(IDs,i)." ",1) : (Ch,0) ), Ch )

# m-th child of ID n
Child(n,m) = word(ChildList(n),m)

# List of leaves, recursive function
LeafList(n) = (LL="", ChildCount(n)==0 ? LL=LL.n." " : sum [i=1:ChildCount(n)] 
(LL=LL.LeafList(Child(n,i)), 0),LL)

# create list of all leaves
LeafAll = LeafList(Start(0))

# get x-position of ID n, recursive function
XPos(n) = ChildCount(n) == 0 ? ItemIdx(LeafAll,n) : (sum [i=1:ChildCount(n)](XPos(Child(n,i))))/(ChildCount(n))

# create the tree datablock for plotting
set print $Tree
do for [j=1:words(IDs)] {
    n = int(word(IDs,j))
    print sprintf("% 3d % 7.2f % 4d % 5s % 8s", n, XPos(n), Level(n), word(Names,j), word(Colors,j))
}
set print
print $Tree

# get x and y distance from ID n to its parent
dx(n) = XPos(Parent(int(n))) - XPos(int(n))
dy(n) = Level(Parent(int(n))) - Level(int(n))

unset border
unset tics
set offsets 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25

array shape[words(IDs)]         # pointtype 6 = circle, pointtype 4 = square
array color[words(IDs)] 
do for [i=1:words(IDs)] { 
 color[i] = int(word(Colors,i))
 shape[i] = int(word(Shape,i)) 
 print sprintf("color[%2d] = %d",i,color[i])
}

plot $Tree u 2:3:(dx($1)):(dy($1)) w vec nohead ls -1 not,\
    "" u 2:3:(shape[$1]+1):(color[$1]) w p pt variable ps 6 lc rgb variable not, \
    "" u 2:3:(shape[$1]) w p pt variable ps 6 lw 1.5 lc rgb "black" not, \
    "" u 2:3:4 w labels offset 0,0.1 center not

### end of code
```

[image]

for a small dataset like this one, the output works perfect

```
  1    2.00    0 y_{45} 0xFE1034
  2    1.00   -1     - 0x118C4B
  3    2.99   -1 y_{37} 0xFE1034
  4    2.00   -2     - 0xC6C1C1
  5    3.98   -2 y_{13} 0xFE1034
  6    3.00   -3     - 0x118C4B
  7    4.97   -3 y_{14} 0xFE1034
  8    4.00   -4     - 0x118C4B
  9    5.94   -4 y_{20} 0xFE1034
 10    5.00   -5     - 0xC6C1C1
 11    6.88   -5 y_{27} 0xFE1034
 12    6.00   -6     - 0xC6C1C1
 13    7.75   -6 y_{41} 0xFE1034
 14    7.00   -7     - 0xC6C1C1
 15    8.50   -7 y_{54} 0xFE1034
 16    8.00   -8     - 0xC6C1C1
 17    9.00   -8     - 0xC6C1C1
```

But, for larger datasets the tree becomes cramped, the nodes overlap, and looks ugly.

[image]

Moreover, when there are more than a few hundred nodes like below, I get a stack overflow error and the plot does not appear. The error comes from this line

```
LeafAll = LeafList(Start(0))
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

```
1 NaN y_{295} 0xFE1034 6 
2 1 x_{0} 0x33B2FF 6 
3 1 y_{1285} 0xFE1034 6 
4 2 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
5 2 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
6 3 x_{3} 0x33B2FF 6 
7 3 y_{18} 0xFE1034 6 
8 6 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
9 6 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
10 7 x_{13} 0x33B2FF 6 
11 7 y_{21} 0xFE1034 6 
12 10 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
13 10 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
14 11 x_{10} 0x33B2FF 6 
15 11 y_{50} 0xFE1034 6 
16 14 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
17 14 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
18 15 - 0x118C4B 4 
19 15 y_{62} 0xFE1034 6 
20 19 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
21 19 y_{48} 0xFE1034 6 
22 21 x_{41} 0x33B2FF 6 
23 21 y_{1839} 0xFE1034 6 
24 22 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
25 22 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
26 23 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
27 23 y_{44} 0xFE1034 6 
28 27 x_{12} 0x33B2FF 6 
29 27 y_{15} 0xFE1034 6 
30 28 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
31 28 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
32 29 x_{58} 0x33B2FF 6 
33 29 y_{127} 0xFE1034 6 
34 32 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
35 32 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
36 33 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
37 33 y_{60} 0xFE1034 6 
38 37 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
39 37 y_{1825} 0xFE1034 6 
40 39 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
41 39 y_{1878} 0xFE1034 6 
42 41 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
43 41 y_{33} 0xFE1034 6 
44 43 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
45 43 y_{3} 0xFE1034 6 
46 45 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
47 45 y_{1435} 0xFE1034 6 
48 47 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
49 47 y_{218} 0xFE1034 6 
50 49 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
51 49 y_{20} 0xFE1034 6 
52 51 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
53 51 y_{13} 0xFE1034 6 
54 53 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
55 53 y_{47} 0xFE1034 6 
56 55 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
57 55 y_{2321} 0xFE1034 6 
58 57 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
59 57 y_{28} 0xFE1034 6 
60 59 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
61 59 y_{52} 0xFE1034 6 
62 61 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
63 61 y_{2410} 0xFE1034 6 
64 63 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
65 63 y_{1751} 0xFE1034 6 
66 65 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
67 65 y_{186} 0xFE1034 6 
68 67 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
69 67 y_{1850} 0xFE1034 6 
70 69 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
71 69 y_{491} 0xFE1034 6 
72 71 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
73 71 y_{23} 0xFE1034 6 
74 73 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
75 73 y_{0} 0xFE1034 6 
76 75 x_{52} 0x33B2FF 6 
77 75 y_{1110} 0xFE1034 6 
78 76 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
79 76 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
80 77 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
81 77 y_{57} 0xFE1034 6 
82 81 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
83 81 y_{12} 0xFE1034 6 
84 83 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
85 83 y_{1269} 0xFE1034 6 
86 85 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
87 85 y_{1278} 0xFE1034 6 
88 87 - 0x118C4B 4 
89 87 y_{63} 0xFE1034 6 
90 89 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
91 89 y_{1338} 0xFE1034 6 
92 91 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
93 91 y_{1271} 0xFE1034 6 
94 93 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
95 93 y_{41} 0xFE1034 6 
96 95 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
97 95 y_{65} 0xFE1034 6 
98 97 - 0x118C4B 4 
99 97 y_{1630} 0xFE1034 6 
100 99 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
101 99 y_{2068} 0xFE1034 6 
102 101 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
103 101 y_{2532} 0xFE1034 6 
104 103 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
105 103 y_{1760} 0xFE1034 6 
106 105 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
107 105 y_{188} 0xFE1034 6 
108 107 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
109 107 y_{2405} 0xFE1034 6 
110 109 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
111 109 y_{1867} 0xFE1034 6 
112 111 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
113 111 y_{1482} 0xFE1034 6 
114 113 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
115 113 y_{79} 0xFE1034 6 
116 115 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
117 115 y_{11} 0xFE1034 6 
118 117 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
119 117 y_{5226} 0xFE1034 6 
120 119 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
121 119 y_{354} 0xFE1034 6 
122 121 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
123 121 y_{2748} 0xFE1034 6 
124 123 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
125 123 y_{27} 0xFE1034 6 
126 125 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
127 125 y_{426} 0xFE1034 6 
128 127 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
129 127 y_{12571} 0xFE1034 6 
130 129 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
131 129 y_{5089} 0xFE1034 6 
132 131 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
133 131 y_{2490} 0xFE1034 6 
134 133 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
135 133 y_{1752} 0xFE1034 6 
136 135 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
137 135 y_{1874} 0xFE1034 6 
138 137 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
139 137 y_{370} 0xFE1034 6 
140 139 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
141 139 y_{1453} 0xFE1034 6 
142 141 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
143 141 y_{2756} 0xFE1034 6 
144 143 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
145 143 y_{545} 0xFE1034 6 
146 145 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
147 145 y_{36} 0xFE1034 6 
148 147 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
149 147 y_{2409} 0xFE1034 6 
150 149 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
151 149 y_{96} 0xFE1034 6 
152 151 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
153 151 y_{82} 0xFE1034 6 
154 153 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
155 153 y_{1788} 0xFE1034 6 
156 155 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
157 155 y_{2812} 0xFE1034 6 
158 157 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
159 157 y_{10357} 0xFE1034 6 
160 159 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
161 159 y_{1801} 0xFE1034 6 
162 161 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
163 161 y_{55} 0xFE1034 6 
164 163 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
165 163 y_{2868} 0xFE1034 6 
166 165 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
167 165 y_{453} 0xFE1034 6 
168 167 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
169 167 y_{31} 0xFE1034 6 
170 169 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
171 169 y_{1281} 0xFE1034 6 
172 171 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
173 171 y_{17} 0xFE1034 6 
174 173 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
175 173 y_{1748} 0xFE1034 6 
176 175 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
177 175 y_{58} 0xFE1034 6 
178 177 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
179 177 y_{2420} 0xFE1034 6 
180 179 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
181 179 y_{7128} 0xFE1034 6 
182 181 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
183 181 y_{11164} 0xFE1034 6 
184 183 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
185 183 y_{1820} 0xFE1034 6 
186 185 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
187 185 y_{1713} 0xFE1034 6 
188 187 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
189 187 y_{387} 0xFE1034 6 
190 189 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
191 189 y_{5253} 0xFE1034 6 
192 191 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
193 191 y_{1699} 0xFE1034 6 
194 193 - 0xC6C1C1 8 
195 193 - 0xC6C1C1 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The depth of gnuplot's evaluation stack is capped at at 250 to prevent run-away recursion.   In order to increase that you would have to edit the source and recompile the program.   If you really want to do that, the relevant definition is here:

```
[gnuplot-5.2.8/src] grep -n -A 3 -B 3 STACK_DEPTH eval.h
44-
45-#include <stdio.h>           /* for FILE* */
46-
47:#define STACK_DEPTH 250              /* maximum size of the execution stack */
48-#define MAX_AT_LEN 150               /* max number of entries in action table */
49-
50-/* These are used by add_action() to index the subroutine list ft[] in eval.c */
```

I have not looked at your recursion algorithm very closely, but I would think it possible to re-order the evaluation so that the subtree information is computed bottom-up rather than top-down.  In that direction it may become purely an iteration rather than a recursive descent.

On the other hand you also say that larger trees don't fit into a single plot.  So another approach may be to split the tree at a depth that both fits on the page and doesn't exceed the stack depth.  Then you restart the process over again for each node that was truncated, and mark that node with an arrow or annotation or other indication like "subtree continued in figure 1b".  Here I have hand-mangled your large figure to show the idea
[image]

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks four your help again. I am collecting the data from python. As you suggested. It was easier to generate the node locations on python and avoid the recursion in gnuplot